# What is the difference between SharedPrefernces and Flutter_secure_storage packages when building an app in flutter? or do they do the same thing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I am trying to build an app in flutter using api tokens and i would like to know if SharedPrefences and flutter_secure_storage packages do the same things or if they are different.

Answer (score 17):

[flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package uses SharedPreferences with MODE_PRIVATE as you can see [here](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.java#L52):

```
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It also uses additional encryption via AES. From [readme](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage#flutter_secure_storage):
`AES encryption is used for Android. AES secret key is encrypted with RSA and RSA key is stored in KeyStore`. You can find details in the [source code](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/tree/develop/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage).

As for secure tokens and other sensitive data, it would be safer to use `flutter_secure_storage` instead of raw SharedPreferences with private mode.

---

#### UPD: WARNING FOR WEB

From package documentation: Flutter Secure Storage uses an experimental implementation using WebCrypto. Use at your own risk at this time.

Comment: @molOko, should warn users about what I wrote below.

Comment: **WARNING**:

From the documentation:

> Flutter Secure Storage uses an experimental implementation using
> WebCrypto. Use at your own risk at this time. Feedback welcome to
> improve it. The intent is that the browser is creating the private
> key, and as a result, the encrypted strings in local_storage are not
> portable to other browsers or other machines and will only work on the
> same domain.
> 
> It is VERY important that you have HTTP Strict Forward Secrecy enabled
> and the proper headers applied to your responses or you could be
> subject to a javascript hijack.